# Table with two foreign keys gives error when trying to run script

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am writing a script that creates a table that is linked to two other tables in the same database. I have decided to use two foreign keys in order to link to the two other tables. When I run the script I get an error (1075), detailing that 'there can only be one auto column and it must be defined as a key'. I believe that I have doe everything correctly and I don't know where I have went wrong. I am using MySQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

---

Code

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
        first_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        second_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        event_date DATE NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (first_id) REFERENCES table1(first_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (second_id) REFERENCES table2(second_id)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

1)
You are trying to create two primary key in single table which is not possible there could be only one auto_increment key in a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
```

> first_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>               second_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

```
        event_date DATE NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (first_id) REFERENCES table1(first_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (second_id) REFERENCES table2(second_id)
        )
```

2) second thing you are trying to make a auto_incremented column as a foreign key of another table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
        first_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        second_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        event_date DATE NOT NULL,
```

> FOREIGN KEY (first_id) REFERENCES table1(first_id),
>               FOREIGN KEY (second_id) REFERENCES table2(second_id)

```
        )
```

**make only one auto_incremented column and which should not be a foreign key of another**

Comment: How would I go about linking to both tables if I were to have only one auto-incrementing foreign key?

Comment: The other two tables that I need to link to both have primary keys that are auto-incrementing. I am unsure as to how to have only one auto-incrementing foreign key, as I then would only be able to link to one able.

Comment: hope this will hel,p you-
`CREATE TABLE entries (
    id smallint auto_increment,
    first_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    second_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (first_id) REFERENCES table1(first_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (second_id) REFERENCES table2(second_id)
);`

Comment: Thanks for the help :). I was just wondering, what are 'id' and 'name', in relation to the script that I had originally provided?

Comment: An update on my situation: When I try to run this script, I am given the same error (1075) ('There can only be one auto column...)

Comment: that was just a example-
Here is the another example for the process you want to do.. may be this will help you. this is just a example depends on which i understand from your query

Comment: 1)
 CREATE TABLE table1 (
 first_id int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (first_id)
) 


2)
 CREATE TABLE table2 (
 second_id int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (second_id)
) 

3) 
 CREATE TABLE entries (
 
 id int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
 first_id int(11) UNSIGNED,
 second_id int(11) UNSIGNED,
 event_date DATE NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 FOREIGN KEY (first_id) REFERENCES table1(first_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (second_id) REFERENCES table2(second_id)
)